# Java: PrintWriter

Tags: java, filewriter, printwriter

I am trying to use **PrintWriter.java** but I am getting a rather strange problem and I am not able to figure out what am I am missing here.

**MyPrintWriter.java**

```
public class MyPrintWriter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File myFile = new File("myFileDirectory/myFileName.txt");
        try {

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(myFile);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
            pw.println("Hello World!");

            pw.close();

        }   catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.err.println("File not found: " + myFile);
        }   catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

}
```

**MyFileWriter.java**

```
public class MyFileWriter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File myFile = new File("myFileDirectory/myFileName.txt");
        try {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(myFile);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

            String input;
            input = br.readLine();
            while(input != null) {
                pw.println(input);
                input = br.readLine();
            }           
            br.close();
            pw.close();

        }   catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.err.println("File not found: " + myFile);
        }   catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

}
```

**MyPrintWriter.java** is happily writing to the **myFileName.txt** file but **MyFileWrite.java** can't.

Could someone help me understand what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to [flush](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#flush%28%29) your print writer.

The [`PrintWriter` constructor with a `FileWriter` parameter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.Writer%29) creates a PrintWriter with `autoFlush` set to off

Calling `pw.flush()` before `pw.close();` should do the trick

Comment: Calling `pw.close()` **implies** `pw.flush()`! There's no need to call `flush()` before `close()`. `autoFlush` only means that after a `println` a `flush()` will be called automatically.

Comment: @Nivas and @Joachim:    `while(input != null) {
    pw.println(input);
    pw.flush();
    input = br.readLine();
   }` works :)

Comment: @skip: are you reading the file **while** your application is still running? If that's what you need, then `autoFlush` might actually be what you need. If all you need is a complete file when your application stops (or when `close()` is called), then your current code in the question should be sufficient.

Comment: @Joachim: Wasn't running it in an application. Was just reading the file.